# Using a SELECT inside of another SELECT statement where the nested SELECT takes as input a value from the first SELECT

Tags: sql-server

First I apologize for the title but I just don't know how to put it in one row.

All master accounts has 1 or more subaccounts. The way is setup is that every account has unique lskinid. If the account is a master-Account lskinid and masterlskin are the same because it hold it's own lskinid. 
If the account is a sub-account then under the column masterlskin it will hold the lskinid of it's master account. With this said, all the accounts, including sub-accounts, has their own account name (refname).
Now here is where the problem starts. I want to select the MASTER ACCOUNT NAME (refname of the master account) and the second column to be the total number of sub-accounts for that master account. Since I am grouping by master-account (masterlskin)
there will be multiple records for account name (refname) but I want to show the refname for the master account.

What I did so far is:

```
SELECT count(lskinid) AS "Total Subaccounts", 
(SELECT refname FROM lskin WHERE lskinid = masterlskin) AS "Account Name"
FROM lskin
WHERE isactive = 1
Group by masterlskin
order by count(lskinid) DESC
```

Table lskin has:
-refname (account name)
-lskinid (accouont id)
-masterlskin (master account id)
-isactive (if is active account)
.
.
.

This doesn't work because the sub-query is returning multiple records, which make sense because it is looking through all the records on that table. Is there any way to tell that sub-query to take the values only on the current row. More precisely, the variable MASTERLSKIN (the one I wrote all capitals on the sub-query) to get the value of the masterlskin on the current row?

Thank you in advance

I am getting this error message:
[image]

Update:
I fixed it. One of the "in" parts was not on square brackets. Added that and now is working perfect.

Comment: The term you are looking for is a *correlated subquery* :)

Comment: @DavidG and it seems that op just needs a `JOIN` (or maybe an `OUTER APPLY`)

Comment: @Lamak Indeed, it's probably the GROUP BY that is confusing OP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT count(lskinid) AS "Total Subaccounts", 
(SELECT refname FROM lskin as [in] WHERE in.lskinid = out.masterlskin) AS "Account Name"
FROM lskin as [Out]
WHERE isactive = 1
Group by masterlskin
order by count(lskinid) DESC
```

Comment: When I run this query I got this error message:

Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'in'.

Comment: Never mind, added the square brackets on the in after the WHERE clause of the correlated subquery and now is working perfect. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're looking for, i mocked up what i think is a similar scenario with temp tables for you to play with.

The inner join gives you a row for each sub account linked to the master, then grouping on the master and counting the sub id's you should end up with what you want. Hope this helps...

```
Declare @MasterAccs TABLE (id int,active bit, name varchar(10))
Declare @SubAccs TABLE (id int,masterid int, name varchar(10))

Insert Into @MasterAccs VALUES (1,1,'Master A')
Insert Into @MasterAccs VALUES (2,0,'Master B')
Insert Into @MasterAccs VALUES (3,1,'Master C')

Insert Into @SubAccs VALUES (1,1,'Sub 1')
Insert Into @SubAccs VALUES (2,1,'Sub 2')
Insert Into @SubAccs VALUES (3,2,'Sub 3')
Insert Into @SubAccs VALUES (4,2,'Sub 4')
Insert Into @SubAccs VALUES (5,2,'Sub 5')
Insert Into @SubAccs VALUES (6,3,'Sub 6')
Insert Into @SubAccs VALUES (7,3,'Sub 7')
Insert Into @SubAccs VALUES (8,3,'Sub 8')
Insert Into @SubAccs VALUES (9,3,'Sub 9')

Select * From @MasterAccs
Select * From @SubAccs

Select m.name AccountName, Count(s.id) TotalSubs 
From @MasterAccs m 
Inner Join @SubAccs s ON m.id = s.masterid 
Where m.active = 1 GROUP BY m.name
```

EDIT:
So how about this given your new info....
Its using a CTE to effectively treat the masters records from your orig as its own table, do the filtering on active in here, then the join on the last select will do the grouping and counting, the count includes the master record, you can always tweak it to account for that, either -1 from the count or exclude the master in the where clause.

```
Declare @lskin TABLE (lskinid int, masterlskin int, name varchar(10))

Insert into @lskin VALUES (1,1,'Master A')
Insert into @lskin VALUES (2,1,'Sub 1')
Insert into @lskin VALUES (3,1,'Sub 2')
Insert into @lskin VALUES (4,4,'Master B')
Insert into @lskin VALUES (5,4,'Sub 1')

;With Masters as (Select name, masterlskin From @lskin where lskinid = masterlskin)
Select M.name MasterName, count(lskinid) SubAccounts 
From Masters M Inner Join @lskin s on M.masterlskin = s.masterlskin 
Group by M.name
```

Comment: It is a little bit different from that scenario because sub-accounts and master-accounts are on the same table.

lskinid    refname         asterlskin
1           GMC                    1
2           GMC Dallas         1
3           GMC Chicago      1
4           Ford                      4

Record number one is a master-account because you can see that lskinid and masterlskin is the same number. However the records 2 and 3 are sub-accounts because they are holding the masterlskin id of the record 1. The record number 4 is another master-account and it has its own masterlskin id.